# Disable SSH Tunnel with KVM VNC Server

Tags: kvm, vnc, ssh-tunneling

Here at work we've set up a KVM server that hosts a couple guest machines.  The KVM itself is headless and we remote into whenever needed, but we would like to be able to VNC into the guests.  I have set up all the VNC options during the guest creation and everything works great for me on OS X with Chicken VNC viewer.  However, my coworker cannot simply VNC into the guest from his Windows 7 machine with TightVNC (also tried other VNC clients).  It seems that the reason for this is that the KVM requires the SSH tunnel for VNC.  My Chicken VNC allows that, but none of the Windows options do.

Can anyone help us either disable the requirement for ssh tunnels, or suggest a VNC client for Windows that does use ssh tunnels, or provide a work around?

Comment: I'm supposing you've already looked at using [putty](http://crl.ucsd.edu/handbook/vnc/) to do the SSH portion?

Comment: I have looked at Putty.  More wondering if there is a way to disable the SSH tunneling.  Do I have to have tunneling enabled?

Comment: What kind of software are you setting up the VM with? Virt-manager, RHEV, etc?

Comment: I do something similar with OpenVPN tunnel instead of SSH tunnel. Can't help with Windows though.

Comment: Pure Qemu-KVM doesn't require tunneling if you run it with e.g.: `-vnc :0`.

Comment: I'm running pure qemu-kvm, yet it still requires tunneling.

Comment: Do you happen to have a firewall?

Comment: Doing VNC without some sort of encryption is a **HORRIBLE, HORRIBLE** idea.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I definitely am not doing this over the internet, this is all local VNC and we are behind a firewall so I dont care about encryption